# React Navigation - Get next screen name for another navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have React Native app with React Navigation. I want to log screen name every time when it changes.

In my app I already have several `stackNavigator`'s and one `switchNavigator` to combine them.

Now I've just added next `onTransitionStart` property to all `stackNavigator`'s:

```
export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    onTransitionStart: transitionProps => {
      console.log('move to: ', transitionProps.scene.route.routeName);
    },
  },
);
```

Mostly it helps and do it just I wanted. However, it doesn't work in cases when I move from one `stackNavigator` to another. Where it is a better way to leave the callback to know that we moved to another `stackNavigator` and get its first screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me helped next one: `createAppContainer` creates the container with `onNavigationStateChange` property. It takes a function with previous and next navigation state as arguments. Both of them have enough data to understand which screen was previous and which will be next one. Since I have this app container in my main App component, it looks next way:

```
  <View>
    /* ... */
    <RootNavigator
      /* ... */
      onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState, action) => {
        if (action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' || action.type === 'Navigation/BACK') {
          const currentNavigator = newState.routes[newState.index];
          const screenName = currentRoute.routes[currentNavigator.index].routeName;
          console.log('Current screen is: ', screenName);
      }
    };}
    />
    /* ... */
  </View>
```

Both `state` objects store the index and routes properties. They represent chosen `stackNavigator` index and the list of `stackNavigator`'s respectively. So we can get the number of chosen navigator and get the index of current route for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually try the below method:

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

render() {
  <NavigationEvents 
    onWillFocus={() => {
      console.log('screenA')
    }}
          />
}
```

Quoted from [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

> NavigationEvents is a React component providing a declarative API to subscribe to navigation events. It will subscribe to navigation events on mount, and unsubscribe on unmount.

Comment: In this case it is not clear where can I get the name of current screen. You see, when I use `onTransitionStart` property, it gets all data about transition in it. So from this `transitionProps` object I can get all data I need. If I will replace it with `NavigationEvents` it will be clear when I get the screen, but I will need to add it to every screen instead of one navigator